# Grid crossing sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, grid

If you take a sheet of graph paper and draw a sloped line that goes `m` units right and `n` units up, you cross `n-1` horizontal and `m-1` vertical gridlines in some sequence. Write code to output that sequence.

For example, `m=5` and `n=3` gives:

[image: Gridlines crossing for m=5, n=3]

Possibly related: [Generating Euclidian rhythms](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49221/20260), [Fibonacci tilings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38356/generate-valid-fibonacci-tilings), [FizzBuzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz)

**Input:** Two positive integers `m,n` that are relatively prime

**Output:** Return or print the crossings as a sequence of two distinct tokens. For example, it could be a string of `H` and `V`, a list of `True` and `False`, or `0`'s and `1`'s printed on separate lines. There can be a separator between tokens as long as it's always the same, and not, say, a variable number of spaces.

**Test cases:**

The first test case gives empty output or no output.

```
1 1 
1 2 H
2 1 V
1 3 HH
3 2 VHV
3 5 HVHHVH
5 3 VHVVHV
10 3 VVVHVVVHVVV
4 11 HHVHHHVHHHVHH
19 17 VHVHVHVHVHVHVHVHVVHVHVHVHVHVHVHVHV
39 100 HHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHH
```

In the format `(m,n,output_as_list_of_0s_and_1s)`:

```
(1, 1, [])
(1, 2, [0])
(2, 1, [1])
(1, 3, [0, 0])
(3, 2, [1, 0, 1])
(3, 5, [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
(5, 3, [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
(10, 3, [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])
(4, 11, [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
(19, 17, [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
(39, 100, [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Today on PPCG: golf Bresenham's Line Drawing Algorithm

Comment: Based on the alternate format you added, can/must the input be repeated as part of the output? Otherwise, I don't understand why the input and output are part of the same list.

Comment: @RetoKoradi No, you shouldn't include the input. I put it in tuples to make it easier to process the test cases.

Comment: I can predict the answer, but it can't hurt to ask: Would it be acceptable to use the space character as one of the output tokens? A consequence would be that there could be significant leading/trailing spaces in the output. There would be no other spaces, so all spaces would be significant.

Comment: @RetoKoradi No, because trailing spaces aren't visible.

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby, 92; [Ostrich 0.7.0](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/ostrich-lang/releases/tag/v0.7.0-alpha), 38

```
f=->m,n{((1..m-1).map{|x|[x,1]}+(1..n-1).map{|x|[1.0*x*m/n,0]}).sort_by(&:first).map &:last}
```

```
:n;:m1-,{)o2W}%n1-,{)m n/*0pW}%+_H$_T%
```

Output for both of them uses 1's and 0's (ex. `101101`).

---

Here's an explanation of the Ostrich one:

```
:n;:m    store n and m as variables, keep m on the stack
1-,      from ex. 5, generate [0 1 2 3]
{...}%   map...
  )        increment, now 5 -> [1 2 3 4]
  o        push 1 (the digit 1 is special-cased as `o')
  2W       wrap the top two stack elements into an array
           we now have [[1 1] [2 1] [3 1] [4 1]]
n1-,     doing the same thing with n
{...}%   map...
  )        increment, now 3 -> [1 2]
  m n/*    multiply by slope to get the x-value for a certain y-value
  0        push 0
  pW       wrap the top two stack elements (2 is special-cased as `p')
+        concatenate the two arrays
_H$      sort-by first element (head)
_T%      map to last element (tail)
```

And an explanation of how the whole thing works, using the Ruby code as a guide:

```ruby
f = ->m,n {
    # general outline:
    # 1. collect a list of the x-coordinates of all the crossings
    # 2. sort this list by x-coordinate
    # 3. transform each coordinate into a 1 or 0 (V or H)
    # observation: there are (m-1) vertical crossings, and (n-1) horizontal
    #   crossings. the vertical ones lie on integer x-values, and the
    #   horizontal on integer y-values
    # collect array (1)
    (
        # horizontal
        (1..m-1).map{|x| [x, 1] } +
        # vertical
        (1..n-1).map{|x| [1.0 * x * m/n, 0] }  # multiply by slope to turn
                                               # y-value into x-value
    )
    .sort_by(&:first)  # sort by x-coordinate (2)
    .map &:last        # transform into 1's and 0's (3)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 53

This uses the True/False list output. Nothing special here.

```
lambda m,n:[x%m<1for x in range(1,m*n)if x%m*(x%n)<1]
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth - <s>32</s> 24 bytes

```
Jmm,chk@Qddt@Qd2eMS+hJeJ
```

Takes input via stdin with the format `[m,n]`.
Prints the result to stdout as a list of 0's and 1's, where 0 = V and 1 = H.

[Test it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Jmm%2Cchk%40Qddt%40Qd2eMS%2BhJeJ&input=%5B39%2C100%5D&debug=0)

---

Explanation:

```
J                           # J = 
 m             2            # map(lambda d: ..., range(2))
  m        t@Qd             # map(lambda k: ..., range(input[d] - 1))
   ,chk@Qdd                 # [(k + 1) / input[d], d]
                eMS+hJeJ    # print map(lambda x: x[-1], sorted(J[0] + J[-1])))
```

Comment: You can save a byte by using the syntactical map operator for the when you're mapping end. `eM` is the same as `med`.

Comment: Also, you can just take out `@"VH"` since you are allowed to print `0` and `1` instead of `V` and `H`.

Comment: You can save yet another byte by using inline assignment with `J`. Here is what I have so far at 25 bytes: https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jkeMS%2BhJmm%2Cchk%40Qddt%40Qd2eJ&input=%5B39%2C100%5D&debug=1

Comment: @Maltysen, thanks I think you can remove `jk` as the output can be a list.

Comment: You can get 23 look at my comment about inline assignment.

Comment: @Maltysen Some nice tips, but try harder. ;-) 16 bytes using the exact same algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

## IA-32 machine code, 26 bytes

Hexdump of the code:

```
60 8b 7c 24 24 8d 34 11 33 c0 2b d1 74 08 73 03
03 d6 40 aa eb f2 61 c2 04 00
```

I started from the following C code:

```
void doit(int m, int n, uint8_t* out)
{
    int t = m;
    while (true)
    {
        if (t >= n)
        {
            t -= n;
            *out++ = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            t += m;
            *out++ = 0;
        }
        if (t == n)
            break;
    }
}
```

It writes the output into the supplied buffer. It doesn't return the length of the output, but it's not really needed: the output length is always `m + n - 2`:

```
int main()
{
    char out[100];
    int m = 10;
    int n = 3;
    doit(m, n, out);
    for (int i = 0; i < m + n - 2; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", out[i]);
    }
}
```

To convert the C code into machine code, I first did some tweaking, to make one of the `if/else` branches empty, and compare with `0` instead of `n`:

```
void doit(int m, int n, char* out)
{
    int t = n;
    while (true)
    {
        int r = 0;
        t -= m;
        if (t == 0)
            break;
        if (t >= 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            t += m + n;
            ++r;
        }
        *out++ = r;
    }
}
```

From here, writing the inline-assembly code is straightforward:

```
__declspec(naked) void __fastcall doit(int x, int y, char* out)
{
    _asm
    {
        pushad;                 // save all registers
        mov edi, [esp + 0x24];  // edi is the output address
        lea esi, [ecx + edx];   // esi is the sum m+n
    myloop:                     // edx is the working value (t)
        xor eax, eax;           // eax is the value to write (r)
        sub edx, ecx;
        jz myout;
        jae mywrite;
        add edx, esi;
        inc eax;
    mywrite:
        stosb;                  // write one value to the output
        jmp myloop;
    myout:
        popad;                  // restore all registers
        ret 4;                  // return (discarding 1 parameter on stack)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious -- why does this algorithm work?

Comment: @xnor Informally, it tracks the *fizzbuzz sequence*. Here `t` is the "distance to `buzz`". If the distance is at least `n`, go `fizz`, else go `buzz`; update the distance; repeat until it's 0.

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 15 bytes

```
Ll~_:*,\ff{%!^}
```

[Try it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=Ll%7E_%3A*%2C%5Cff%7B%25!%5E%7D&input=%5B5%203%5D)

It prints `01` for V and `10` for H.

#### Explanation

```
L          e# An empty list.
l~         e# Evaluate the input.
_:*,       e# [0, m*n).
\          e# The input (m and n).
ff{%!      e# Test if each number in [0, m*n) is divisible by m and n.
^}         e# If divisible by m, add an 10, or if divisible by n, add an 01 into
           e# the previous list. If divisible by neither, the two 0s cancel out.
           e# It's just for output. So we don't care about what the previous list
           e# is -- as long as it contains neither 0 or 1.
```

The diagonal line crosses a horizontal line for every 1/n of the whole diagonal line, and crosses a vertical line for every 1/m.

Comment: Will you add an explanation for this? It's very intriguing, but at least from an initial quick look I don't understand why it works. From playing with it, I notice that it only works for values that are relative primes (which is given in the problem description), while mine works for all values. So the underlying math is obviously very different.

Comment: After letting it sink in some more, I believe I understand at least the algorithm part. Have to study the output generation logic later.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Edited.

Answer (score 3):

## Python - 125 bytes

Uses a very simple algorithm, just increments the coordinates and detects when it crosses the lines and prints out. Am looking to translate to Pyth.

```
a,b=input()
i=1e-4
x=y=l=o=p=0
k=""
while len(k)<a+b-2:x+=i*a;y+=i*b;k+="V"*int(x//1-o//1)+"H"*int(y//1-p//1);o,p=x,y
print k
```

That while loop is checking the number of `l`ines and then checking if any of the values went over an int boundary by subtracting.

Takes input like `39, 100` from stdin and prints out like `HHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHHVHHHVHH` to stdout in one line.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 32

```
Prompt M,N
For(X,1,MN-1
gcd(X,MN
If log(Ans
Disp N=Ans
End
```

Straightforward. Uses a sequence of `0` and `1`, separated by linebreaks. TI-BASIC's advantages are the two-byte `gcd(` and implied multiplication, but its disadvantages are the For loop including the end value and the 5 bytes spent for input.

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 47

```python
lambda m,n:[m>i*n%(m+n)for i in range(1,m+n-1)]
```

Like [anatolyg's algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52133/20260), but checked directly with moduli.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
PLIδÖʒO
```

Inspired by [*@jimmy23013*'s CJam answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52533/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

Input as a pair of integers \$[m,n]\$ and output as a list of `[0,1]` and `[1,0]` pairs for \$V\$ and \$H\$ respectively.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a8UHW2go2AYq6MQbaijYACiYXys4rFKMf8DfDzPbTk87dQk////o011jGMB) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WeXhCqL2SwqO2SQpK9v8DfCLObTk87dQk//@1Ov@jow11DGN1gKQRkDSCso2BpDFYxFjHFEiagkUMDcCUiY4hWJWljqE5SAWQNjCIjQUA).

**Explanation:**

```python
P        # Take the product of the (implicit) input-pair: m*n
 L       # Pop and push a list in the range [1, m*n]
  IδÖ    # Check for each value in this list, whether each value in the input-pair evenly
         # divides it (resulting in [0,0] if the number is neither divisible by `m` nor `n`;
         # [0,1] if the number is only divisible by `m`;
         # [1,0] if the number is only divisible by `n`;
         # [1,1] for the final number m*n, which is divisible by both `m` and `n` obviously)
     ʒ   # Then filter this list of pairs, keeping only the pairs which are truthy for:
      O  #  Where the sum of the pair is exactly 1 (NOTE: only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E)
         # (after which the resulting list is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 78 bytes

```
import Data.List
m#n=map snd$sort$[(x,0)|x<-[1..m-1]]++[(y*m/n,1)|y<-[1..n-1]]
```

Usage example:

```
*Main> 19 # 17
[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
*Main> 10 # 3
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
```

How it works: make a list of the x-values of all vertical crossings `(x,0)` for `x` in [1,2,...,m-1] (`0` indicates vertical) and append the list of the x-values of all horizontal crossings `(y*m/n,1)` for `y` in [1,2,...,n-1] (`1` indicates horizontal). Sort and take the second elements of the pairs.

Curse of the day: again I have to spent 17 bytes on the `import` because `sort` is in `Data.List` and not in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```
l~:N;:M{TN+Mmd:T;0a*1}*>
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l~%3AN%3B%3AM%7BTN%2BMmd%3AT%3B0a*1%7D*%3BW%3C&input=5%203)

Very straightforward, pretty much a direct implementation of a Bresenham type algorithm.

Explanation:

```
l~    Get input and convert to 2 integers.
:N;   Store away N in variable, and pop from stack.
:M    Store away M in variable.
{     Loop M times.
  T     T is the pending remainder.
  N+    Add N to pending remainder.
  M     Push M.
  md    Calculate div and mod.
  :T;   Store away mod in T, and pop it from stack
  0a    Wrap 0 in array so that it is replicated by *, not multiplied.
  *     Emit div 0s...
  1     ... and a 1.
}*      End of loop over M.
>       Pop the last 1 and 0.
```

The last `01` needs to be popped because the loop went all the way to the end point, which is not part of he desired output. Note that we can **not** simply reduce the loop count by 1. Otherwise, for `N > M`, all the `0`s from the last iteration will be missing, while we only need to get rid of the very last `0`.

Comment: You can use `>` for `;W<`.

Comment: @jimmy23013 Good idea. Since I know that I have a `1` on top of the stack, I might as well use it productively.

Answer (score 1):

## KDB(Q), 44 bytes

```
{"HV"0=mod[asc"f"$1_til[x],1_(x*til y)%y;1]}
```

## Explanation

Find all *x* axis values of intersect points and sort them. If mod 1 is zero its "V", non-zero is "H".

## Test

```
q){"HV"0=mod[asc"f"$1_til[x],1_(x*til y)%y;1]}[5;3]
"VHVVHV"
```